# Error: unrecognized opcode `mul a0,t4,t5', extension `m' or `zmmul' required

Tags: assembly, riscv, gnu-toolchain

I'm trying to compile RISC-V assembly code to object file. I've built `riscv-gnu-toolchain`, selecting newlib, architecture `rv32imac` and abi `ilp32`.

However, when I try to compile assembly code with command: `riscv32-unknown-elf-as -march=rv32imac -mabi=ilp32 main.s -o main.o`, I'm getting: `Error: unrecognized opcode 'mul a0,t4,t5', extension 'm' or 'zmmul' required`.

I don't really understand, why I'm getting this. In both cases (building the toolchain and compiling the code) I specified `m` extension, but it looks like `riscv32-unknown-elf-as` doesn't detect it.

Do you know, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem: in source code I had the line `.attribute 5, "rv32i2p0"` that was overriding `-march` option from command line. I changed it to `.attribute   5, "rv32imac"` and fixed the problem.

Comment: Works here. What version of binutils?

Comment: I used the default binutils (located inside `riscv-gnu-toolchain` repo)

Comment: That does not help. What is the version number (`as --version`)

Comment: GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-linux-gnu'.

Comment: Should I rebuild/install binutils for riscv?

Comment: *This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-linux-gnu`* - That's your system assembler, `as --version`.  Not the `riscv32-unknown-elf-as` you used to assemble your RISC-V source.

Comment: Does your source have any directives that override the `-march` from the command line?  A [mcve] would include a source file (probably just one line) and an `as` version (for `riscv32-unknown-elf-as` of course).  And any config options you used when building the toolchain yourself.

Comment: `riscv32-unknown-elf-as` returns: 
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.40.0.20230214
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `riscv32-unknown-elf'.

Comment: I found the bug. Indeed, as @PeterCordes mentioned, I had in source code the attribute that overrode `-march` from CLI. Thanks y'all.